# After installing SUPEE-6788 no homepage products displaying

Tags: magento-1.9

After installing the supree 6788 patch, products are now not displaying on our homepage? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

Just realised how to fix this.

This new update adds a section in your admin.

System - permission - blocks. 
You must add the home page blocks ie. filterproducts/latest_home_list to your allowed permissions.

Reload the homepage and they should be back

Comment: Be sure to replace 'filterproducts/latest_home_list' with your own block name or type.